# Turbogears 2.1 with mako - extensive tutorial

Tags: turbogears2

I am a python programmer.

For web-based solutions, I have started learning TG 2.1

By and large, the documentation on TG 2.1 official site is a work-in-process.

As regards to the templates, it tells how to go about Genshi.

I wish to go with mako.

Gone through the docs of mako (they are good).

But still, it would be better if I can get a tutorial explaining using TG 2.1 with mako.
(It will save me from re-inventing the wheel, if somebody has written docs on these lines).

Can anybody point to a tutorial for using TG 2.1 with mako.?
(I googled, but no convincing result was found).

Thanks,
Vineet.

Answer (score 0):

When you run "**paster quickstart**" it should ask you if you want to proceed with genshi or mako. If you choose make the quickstart will set everything up for you and your project will be mako based.

If you want to add mako to an existing project to render only some templates with mako or for just for curiosity you can take a look at http://www.turbogears.org/2.1/docs/main/Templates/Mako.html to see how to add the mako renderer and render mako templates in TG2